# Django can't save userprofile instance during saving forms

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am getting this error

> Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<UserProfile: UserProfile object (131)>]>": "BlogComment.userprofile" must be a "UserProfile" instance.

when saving my form.

Here is my code:

```
if request.method == "POST":
       if comment_form.is_valid():
                isinstance = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                name = request.POST['name']
                email = request.POST['email']
                if request.user.is_authenticated:
                   user_profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
                   isinstance.blog = blog
                   isinstance.user = request.user
                   isinstance.name = name
                   isinstance.email = email
                   isinstance.userprofile = user_profile
                   isinstance.save()
```

**models.py**

```
class BlogComment(models.Model):
       userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
       #others fields....
```

In my models I have foreign key named `userprofile` so I am trying to save this instance like this:

```
isinstance.userprofile = user_profile
```

Where am I going wrong? What is my mistake?

I'm using this call for getting current user profile:

```
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variable:

```
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

seems to be whole QuerySet. It has to be only one object. Like this:

```
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```